# Can you use macros to make a "self" return type?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to write classes with chain-able operators (similar to JQuery), where instead of returning void, the function returns the object/pointer it was called on so you can perform more functions on it. For example:

```
Foo* Foo::bar(Bar value){
    _bar = value;
    return this;
}
```

Obviously the least hack-y way to do it would be to uses the object's own class as a return type, as above, but I was wondering if there was a way to shorten this using macros. For instance:

```
self Foo::bar(Bar value){
    _bar = value;
}
```

The macro would basically replace itself with the class the method belongs to and add "return this;" to the end. Is this possible? And if so, is it a good idea, or should I stick to the usual method?

Comment: Do you know what a macro is?  Text substitutions can't insert code (i.e. `return this;`) anywhere there isn't already a placeholder.

Comment: stick with the common convention. it will help with readability.

Comment: This would certainly not be a good idea and result in pretty unreadable code. If you feel like you are typing too much, get a better text editor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm only slightly familiar with them (haven't used C++ for a while). I take it the `return this;` part wouldn't be possible. What about the class substitution?

Comment: you can use c++14 return type deduction by declaring the return type be `auto`. BTW your "least hack-y way" is much _less_ readable and _more_ hacky IMO.

Comment: `auto` would probably be the better way to go. I thought that was just a C# thing, but if C++ also has it I'll use that, instead. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to slightly reduce the boilerplate for operators without macros. For example, you could associate operator templates which use certain (possibly free) functions for the actual work. If you make those operator templates specific to your task, you could indeed boil down the implementation to something like `auto& bar_impl() { return this->bar; }` (as a member function).

Comment: @Mr.Underhill89: C# *doesn't* have `auto`, and `var` cannot be used for return types.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: (BTW you still have multiple syntax errors apart from the actual hypothetical feature, for example the scope operator is `::` not `:`, and a member variable can't overload a member function.)

Comment: That's what I get for writing in a hurry. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are worrying about small things. Over the life time of a project, the difference in the time taken to write

```
Foo* Foo::bar(Bar value){
    _bar = value;
    return this;
}
```

vs

```
self Foo::bar(Bar value){
    _bar = value;
}
```

is so small, it's not even worth discussing. If you take into account the loss of readability in the second block of code, I would say the second approach will cost you more than the first method over time. Not only that, you'll also have to come up with two macros -- one for `const` member functions and one for non-`const` member functions.

BTW, I would recommend using `Foo&` as return time.

```
Foo& Foo::bar(Bar value){
    _bar = value;
    return *this;
}
```

Returning a pointer makes sense only if there is a possibility that the function can return NULL to signify failure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend it, but it might be possible to use an approach like:

```
#define self(T,memname,arglist) T* T::memname arglist { memname##impl REMOVETYPES(arglist); return this; } void T::memname##impl arglist

self(Foo,bar,(Bar value))
{
    this.internal_bar = value;
}
```

Note that this no longer looks anything like a member declaration.  If you're going to go this direction, might as well make a macro for chainable setters:

```
#define DEFINE_SETTER(T,setterName,MemType,MemName) T* T::setterName(MemType value) { MemName = value; return this; }

DEFINE_SETTER(Foo,setBar,Bar,bar)
```

This latter version at least is obviously a macro-based code generator, not pretending to be a weird form of real C++.

But I guess I question the value of forcing the consumer to use a function, when there's no logic whatsoever, just directly exposing the ability to overwrite a member variable.

Comment: "But I guess I question the value of forcing the consumer to use a function, when there's no logic whatsoever, just directly exposing the ability to overwrite a member variable."

That was just a (poorly-written) example. The real code would have validation logic built in.